# How to get keywords from Google HTTP referrer?

Tags: google-search, http-headers, referrer

Can the http referrer URL from Google be decoded so that I can see the specific keywords?

```
http://www.google.sk/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=11&sqi=2&ved=0CFgQFjAK&url=http://www.peciatky.sk/238-plombovacie-klieste.html&ei=WastU8_WMI-O7QautoCYBg&usg=AFQjCNHAZhWGZeIoJGtAOoSgSG25l4Hyqw
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Unfortunately, you can't. Google search now exclusively uses HTTPS and all search result clicks go through an intermediate URL that removes the keywords. The URL you posted above appears to be that intermediate URL, and that's all you get as the referrer.

The reasoning behind this is that each user of Google often gets personalised results based on their search history, so if a visitor's referrer contains the search terms for your site it could potentially 'leak' information about that user.

You should create a [Google Search Console](https://search.google.com/search-console/about) account, which will allow you to see anonymised summaries of what keywords sent people to your site. If you use Google Analytics you can also link the two accounts to see the same data in Analytics.

Comment: Thanks, I already have a Webmaster account - was just curious if I could get more info about my visitors.

Comment: Thats a complete gamebreaker for analytics and business sale concepts. We cannot proof to our customers that a specific user did not came from a brand / shopname search but from a keyword search we are responsible of since we optimized the shop. This is important for negotations since some clients are interested in different referral fee / provision based the customers they had before us and new customers. Google should allow this as an opt-in feature for honest sites.

Answer (score 2):

This website decodes the url for you but there's not too much information in there. https://gqs-decoder.appspot.com/

```
scheme : http
netloc : www.google.sk
path : /url
params :
query :
    usg : AFQjCNHAZhWGZeIoJGtAOoSgSG25l4Hyqw
    ei : WastU8_WMI-O7QautoCYBg
    rct : j
    ved : 0CFgQFjAK
    VisitEventDescriptor (ved):
        result_position : 10
        index_boost : 88
        type : web (22)
    cd : 11
    source : web
    sqi : 2
    esrc : s
    url : http://www.peciatky.sk/238-plombovacie-klieste.html
    sa : t
fragment:
```